# Получить уникальные значение через связь моделей Laravel

Tags: php, база-данных, laravel, laravel-5.7

Мне нужно получить уникалные значения из таблицы Payment_types учитывая связи.
В проекте есть такие таблицы как:
 1. Products [поля:id,name];
 2. Pharmacies [поля:id,name];
 3. Payment_types [поля:id,name];
 4. Pharmacy_products[поля:id_pharmacy, id_product];
 5. Pharmacy_payment_methods[поля:id_pharmacy,id_payment_type];
Так же есть модели:

```
class Product extends Model
{
  public function pharmacy()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Pharmacy',
            'pharmacy_products');
    }  
}
class Pharmacy extends Model
{
   public function paymentMethods()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\PaymentMethod',
            'pharmacy_payment_methods');
    }
 }
```

Модели других таблиц так же существуют. В них лишь стандартный protected $fillable.
Как мне правильно получить уникальные имена видов оплат?
Я пробовал разные комбинации например:

```
$data['product'] = Product::find($id);  
$payment_types = $data['product']->pharmacy->paymentMethods->distinct('name');
```

И разные другие вариации, но постоянно получаю разного рода ошибки,  я подозреваю что есть элегатное и верное решение этой задачи.

Comment: У вас не правильные названия полей - id_pharmacy, к примеру, должна быть pharmacy_id. Смотрите примеры в официальной документации и следуйте примерам в Интернете.

Answer (score 1):

Если у вас правильно настроены связи используйте
**Nested Eager Loading**

`$product = Product::with('pharmacy.paymentMethods')->find($id);`

Answer (score 1):

ЭЛЕГАНТНОЕ решение заключается в том, чтобы сделать в базе данных предаставление (view) на SQL, такое как вы хотите. А уже из него получать те уникальные данные которые вам нужны стандартными методами.